# Exit macro for closing Chrome or other browser in powerpoint

Tags: vba, browser, powerpoint, exit

i made this:

```
  ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink _
    Address:="http://192.168.16.49/?OUT1=ON", _
    NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=False
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (2)
              
              
End Sub
```

Now it opens Chrome to show the page. but i wan't to close that page also directly. wat do i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've used IE for that, but you've got to set time to closure or just add some msgbox if it's clicked then close the IE.

```
Sub OpenClose()

    Dim ieBrowser As Object
    Set ieBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    ieBrowser.Visible = True
    ieBrowser.Navigate "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693100/exit-macro-for-closing-chrome-or-other-browser-in-powerpoint"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) ' set your time or add Msgbox("Test")
    
    ieBrowser.Quit
    Set ieBrowser = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use this code and set timer for your adress and everything would be fine.
It's a different way of sloving this issue. There is no way to close HyperLink when opening it.